# Graphics device is not getting populated

Tags: gpu

I have been following the [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/297/cycles-render-not-utilizing-the-gpu-as-it-should?rq=1) about the GPU enabling in blender and found that the device name is not populated. Does this mean the device is not configured with blender? 
[image]

Comment: What kind of GPU are you using? and what options do you get when you **click** on GraphicsDevice?

Comment: GTX Titan X is the graphics card I have. I see no options when I click on Graphics device.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles

Comment: THanks! I followed that post and before that I didn't even have the option of CUDA. Now I have that but my device is not recognized.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Have you tried rendering on it? It could be that it's working, but the name is strange for some reason (related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/31795/599)

Comment: Yes it is rendering the scene. But there is no difference in the time of computation. Does it depend on something else?